# Access a PayPal unique transaction ID

Tags: php, paypal

How can I access PayPal unique transaction ID using IPN with PHP?

Can I access this from the auto return too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the transaction ID on the IPN callback. Look for PHP example code in the IPN documentation.

You can set up a sandbox account so you can do your IPN testing. This is how I did it.

Overall I found it infuriatingly difficult to figure out exactly what PayPal's API looks like. It's a very messy API and the documentation is very confusing.

Comment: Yeha have got all this working, but im unsure which variable to call in order to get a unique ID, such as transaction ID

Comment: Am i right in thinking its txn_id, would this be unique for each sale?

Comment: PayPal guarantees that it is unique. Do keep in mind that you can still get multiple request _for the same transaction_ because PayPal may retry if it doesn't get a reply from your server. So always double check what PayPal sends you.

Comment: Yeah got it working now, was a error in my PHP code Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an function checktxn($tx_id)
You have txn_id on $_POST['txn_id'];

```
checktxn($tid)
{
  $query = "SELECT txn_id FROM already WHERE txn_id = ?";
  if ($stmt = $this->linkmysqli->prepare($query))
  {
     $stmt->bind_param('i',$tid);
     ....
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->bind_result($return_id);
     ....
  }
if (!$return_id)
echo "it's cool";
else
echo "it's NOT cool"; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The [IPN Code Samples](https://merchant.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt) lists the code you want. The specific line you're looking for is:

```
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
```